# Python not equal to 0

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse, pydev

I am new to Python. How can I know if a function is being used or not; if it is not equal to zero then the program will print; otherwise, do not print any zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there... but you need to use **!=** and **:** in your **if** statement

Using the 'if' statement :-

```
            b1 = (int(a1[0]) + int(a2[0])) // 10
            if b1!=0:
              print(b1)
```

Answer (score 2):

use != for condition check

```
b1 = (int(a1[0]) + int(a2[0])) // 10

if b1 != 0:

    print (b1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even do not use != to check "not equality" with 0

```
v = 0
if v: # instead of v!=0
   print ("Invisible")

v = 100
if v: # instead of v!=0
   print ("Visible")
```